# UIView animation is delayed

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

An app i am developing is pulling in custom ads.  I'm retrieving ads fine, and the network side of things are working correctly.  The problem I'm having is when the AdController receives an ad it parses the JSON object then requests the image.

```
// Request the ad information
NSDictionary* resp = [_server request:coords_dict isJSONObject:NO responseType:JSONResponse];
// If there is a response...
if (resp) {
    // Store the ad id into Instance Variable
    _ad_id = [resp objectForKey:@"ad_id"];
    // Get image data
    NSData* img = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[resp objectForKey:@"ad_img_url"]]];
    // Make UIImage
    UIImage* ad = [UIImage imageWithData:img];
    // Send ad to delegate method
    [[self delegate]adController:self returnedAd:ad];
}
```

All this works as expected, and AdController pulls in the image just fine...

```
-(void)adController:(id)controller returnedAd:(UIImage *)ad{
    adImage.image = ad;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        adImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 372, 320, 44);
    }];
    NSLog(@"Returned Ad (delegate)");
}
```

The When the delegate method is called, it logs the message to the console, but it takes up to 5-6 seconds for the `UIImageView* adImage` to animate in.  Because of the way the app is handling the request of the ads, the animation needs to be instant.

The animation for hiding the ad is immediate.

```
-(void)touchesBegan{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        adImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 417, 320, 44);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the ad-loading happens in a background thread (the easiest way to check is `[NSThread isMainThread]`), then you cannot update the UI state in the same thread! Most of UIKit is not thread-safe; certainly UIViews currently be displayed are not. What's probably happening is that the main thread does not "notice" the change happening in the background thread, so it's not flushed to screen until something else happens.

```
-(void)someLoadingMethod
{
  ...
  if (resp)
  {
    ...
    [self performSelectorInMainThread:@selector(loadedAd:) withObject:ad waitUntilDone:NO];
  }
}

-(void)loadedAd:(UIImage*)ad
{
  assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
  [[self delegate] adController:self returnedAd:ad];
}
```

Comment: The network request is happening in a background thread but when it calls the background delegate, shouldn't that be pushed to the thread the delegate object is in? Should I implicitly tell it to dispatch the delegate method on the main Queue?

Comment: I went ahead an told the delegate to dispatch on the main queue and it's behaving as normal now.

Comment: That'll depend on the code in AdController. Most sensible APIs expect to be used from the main thread and run delegate methods on the main thread, but there may be a few that aren't as carefully designed. If it is running in the main thread, then you don't want to be calling `-[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` which is blocking.

Comment: `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` is running in a background thread.  That's the problem I was having, was that it was all running in a background thread and UIView animations weren't being updated to the screen.